# What is wrong with my Nintendo Entertainment System?

Tags: technical-issues, nes

I'm having issues getting my Nintendo Entertainment System working.

When the cartridge is inserted just right, the screen shows up, but the pointer just alternates between choices on the screen, back and forth, and no controllers are working (I tried 5 different ones). I have tried the cleaning out the 72 connectors and that fixed my original problem of having a grey screen of death.

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail? What "pointer" are you referring to?

Comment: May be a bad controller port.  After all, if it's an original NES, it is over 20 years old!

Comment: pointer would be the selector on main menus. like the arrow that 'pointed' to start game that appeared a lot on old games.

Comment: Have you tried it with a different controller or different game? It sounds like the Select button is constantly sending a signal, so you'll probably need to use a different controller.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by the use of the word "pointer" you mean perhaps an arrow to select the start of a game, it can either be a controller port issue, or an issue with your game. Try using another game to see if that happens again.